# Test two independent windows with Karma

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, karma-runner, karma-mocha

How can I write tests with Karma/Mocha/Chai that are independent? For instance, the following tests will pass:

```
'use strict'

describe("test 1", function () {
  it("has a new window", function() {
    expect(window.test).to.be.undefined;
    window.test = 123;
  });
});

describe("test 2", function () {
  it("has not a new window", function() {
    expect(window.test).to.be.equal(123);
  });
});
```

While I'd like the second test to happen in a new environment, and then to fail here. My Karma conf is in single run mode and doesn't autowatch.